# How to make 2 activities with listviews, one that gets future events, and one that gets past events, with the actual date

Tags: java, android, listview

I'm trying to think of a way that I can make a App that is simple, but I don't know what I can use to make. 2 listviews with a botton navigation bar, wwhere I get the current date and show 2 list, one with events that will happen soon, and one with events that happened soon. I looks like the App TV Time, but it's another type of events, and for a school project. If anyone knows ways I can do it. I don't know how can I make the current date and divide the listing in the 2 lists that I need. Any help is appretiated.

Comment: Make it however you want? Have you tried anything so far? StackOverflow isn't a free code-writing service, and expects you to [**try to solve your own problem first**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592). Please update your question to show what you have already tried, showcasing a **specific** problem you are facing in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For further information, please see [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [**tour of the site**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: I'm still in the thinking phase, I don't want code written, only ideas of how I can get the current date, and if I have to do the 2 lists as views in the BD. I'm still on the idea of the app, not developing.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement ViewPager and 2 fragments for your lists . Getting Date and Time is this code

```
   private String getDate(){
    DateFormat dfDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
    String date=dfDate.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
    DateFormat dfTime = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
    String time = dfTime.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
    return date + " " + time;
}
```